# Flux .then() running before complete signal

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactjs-flux, flatmap

I tried to do something with Flux streaming objects and after handling all elements do some last work and finish a Mono but it doesn't work:

```
 // data and id comming from a webrequest
 // myRepository is a org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository
 myRepository.findById(id)
    .flatMap(dbObject -> doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave(dbObject , data))
    .then (doOnFinish(data))
    .subscribe();

Mono<DbObject> doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave (DbObject dbo, DataObject data){
...
}
Mono<Void> doOnFinish(DataObject data){
...
}
```

The problem:
Even I try this, the function "doOnFinish" is called before the first element pass doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave" but I change something on the data object and would like to do this before!

The I tried to change the code:

```
myRepository.findById(id)
        .flatMap(dbObject -> doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave(dbObject , data))
        .last()
        .flatMap(dbObject  -> doOnFinish(data))
        .subscribe();
```

I hoped, that I could use the last element to trigegr the onFinish function but I got
"flux#last() didn't observe any onnext signal" and do not undetstand this!

Anyone any idea?

Comment: You are calling `.then (doOnFinish(data))` which will immediately call `doOnFinish` wtih `data` as its input; IOW: the method call is evaluated eagerly. That should probably be `.then(data -> doOnFinish(data))` or whatever the overload is called. (similar to your `flatMap` call).

Comment: @knittl you are right. He should use the `then` flavor that takes a Mono as argument, and create a deferred or callable Mono : `myFlux.then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> doOnFinish(data));`

Comment: one of the key things you need to understand switching to reactive - Assembly vs Subscription time. Check https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription for details

Answer (score 2):

I think flatMap is redundant here. Instead, you can wrap doOnFinish in a Mono.defer():

```
 myRepository.findById(id)
    .flatMap(dbObject -> doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave(dbObject , data))
    .then (Mono.defer(() -> doOnFinish(data)))
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

`then(methodCall(data))` will eagerly evaluate the parameter expression and thus call `methodCall` even before `then` is entered. You need a method which lazily evaluates its parameters.

I *think* you are looking for [`doOnComplete`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnComplete-java.lang.Runnable-):

> ```
> public final Flux<T> doOnComplete(Runnable onComplete)
> ```
>
> Add behavior (side-effect) triggered when the Flux completes successfully.

```
myRepository.findById(id)
    .flatMap(dbObject -> doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave(dbObject , data))
    .doOnComplete(() -> doOnFinish(data))
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: That could work, but I may have shortened my scenario a bit:
Originally I would like to

return myRepository.findById(id) ......

If I call doOnFinsh() onComplete as @knittl suggested, I would return the Flux Object from the second line. But I want to return the Mono<void> from "doOnFinish", that the subscriber could controll the completion of "doOnFinish"?

Answer (score 0):

Wow ... hours later I found a solution.
doOnComplete doesn't return the stream with the async call from doOnFinish (Mono).
Now I found this:

```
myRepository.findById(id)
   .flatMap(dbObject -> doSomethingWithDbObjectAndSave(dbObject , data))
   .takeLast(1)
   .flatMap(dbObject  -> doOnFinish(data))
   .subscribe();
```

That works for me ....